# The method eth_compileSolidity does not exist/is not available at Object.InvalidResponse stacktrace

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain

I am new to Ethereum. Trying to run a smart contract. I verified the contract content by running it on online compiler. But I am getting an error at the following line of code.

```
var simpleCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(contractcontent);
```

I tried it with web3 version 0.15.3 and 0.20.1 but same error is repeated.

Comment: I believe that method has been deprecated and removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try solc

Setup :

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc
```

Command :

```
solc FundSplitter.sol --combined-json abi,asm,ast,bin,bin-runtime,clone-bin,devdoc,interface,opcodes,srcmap,srcmap-runtime,userdoc > contracts.json
```

Then contract.json has all required elements such as ABI, CODE etc

Answer (score 0):

Compiling via RPC has been removed.
Detail: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3793